# application in gateway cannot reach the network

Tags: networking, router

I am trying to port an application(streamripper) to a wireless router(gateway), which is configured as following : The 1st ethernet port is treated as WAN port. The other ethernet ports and the wireless interface are bridged together and are treated as LAN ports. However, an error encountered and saying that the network is unreachable. The router is working fine and I can ping to the other router which is connected to the real WAN from the terminal of my target wireless router. The path of wireless to the ethernet is also ok. The question is : what am I missing to let the upper layer application to connect to the network? any help is appreciated

ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:43:30:50:10
          inet addr:192.168.0.191  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2016 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:273027 (266.6 KiB)  TX bytes:84282 (82.3 KiB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:43:30:50:77
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10226 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6549 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8134873 (7.7 MiB)  TX bytes:2078363 (1.9 MiB)
          Interrupt:3

eth2.1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:43:30:50:77
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7604939 (7.2 MiB)  TX bytes:493261 (481.7 KiB)

eth2.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:43:30:50:66
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:438 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:257100 (251.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:504 (504.0 B)  TX bytes:504 (504.0 B)

ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:43:30:50:10
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4589 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:526905 (514.5 KiB)  TX bytes:7606898 (7.2 MiB)
          Interrupt:4

Comment: Don't you have a real WAN port on your router/gateway?

Comment: it has. and it connects to the LAN port of the main router. The main router routing all traffic to the internet